# jquery datetime picker set start and end of day

Tags: jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

I need to limit the range of available times to be between 12 and 23 (24 hour clock) with 10 minute steps.

`12:00, 12:10, 12:20, 12:30` and so on all the way to `22:50`.

`allowTimes` is one option. But one would need to write all those times into the code.

By using `step:` the list with times is correct. But it starts all the way down at `00:00`.

```
$('#hyperbowling_datetime').datetimepicker({
    format:'d.m.Y H:i',
    lang:'no',
    startDate:'+1971/05/01',//or 1986/12/08
    hourMin: 12,
    hourMax: 23,
    step:10,
    /*
    allowTimes:[
        '12:00', '13:30', '15:00', '16:30', 
        '17:00', '18:00', '18:30',
    ]
    */
});
```

Is there a quick solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass "immediately invoked function" to allowTimes option and then generate the hours array using for loop like the below one :

```
 allowTimes: function getHours() {
        var hours = [];
          for(var i=12; i <= 24; i++) {
            hours.push( i + ":00");
        }
    return hours;
    }()
```

Comment: Yes. But that does `12:00`, `13:00`, `14:10`... How do I change it to count steps of 10 minutes? Like `12:10`, `12:20`, `12:30`...

Comment: You can write like this 
     for(var i=12; i <= 24; i++) {
          hours.push( i + ":00");
         for(var j=10;j<=60;j+=10){
            hours.push( i + ":"+j);
            }
        }